# Proper way to set response status and JSON content in a REST API made with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express

I am playing around with Nodejs and express by building a small rest API. My question is, what is the good practice/best way to set the code status, as well as the response data?

Let me explain with a little bit of code (I will not put the node and express code necessary to start the server, just the router methods that are concerned):

```
router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = users.getUserById(req.params.id);
  res.json(user);
});


exports.getUserById = function(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].id == id) return users[i];
  }
};
```

The code below works perfectly, and when sending a request with Postman, I get the following result:
[image]

As you can see, the status shows 200, which is OK. But is this the best way to do this? Is there a case where I should have to set the status myself, as well as the returned JSON? Or is that always handled by express?

For example, I just made a quick test and slightly modified the get method above:

```
router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = users.getUserById(req.params.id);
  if (user == null || user == 'undefined') {
    res.status(404);
  }
  res.json(user);
});
```

As you can see, if the user is not found in the array, I will just set a status of 404.

Resources/advices to learn more about this topic are more than welcome.

Comment: This is my highest rated answer and it's not accepted :( @dukable, I know it's been a while, but did it resolve your issue?

Comment: @MichałDudak: Yes, your answer should be the accepted one. But this dukable user is not active since oct 15 2015 (as on Jul 31 2017). +1 for your answer anyways ;)

Answer (score 293):

Express API reference covers this case.

See [status](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status) and [send](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send).

In short, you just have to call the `status` method before calling `json` or `send`:

```
res.status(500).send({ error: "boo:(" });
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment. If you set the status to 204 (No content) it doesn't send the body.

Comment: @internet-nico `res.sendStatus(400);` send a string data too, is equivalent to `res.status(400).send('Not Found')`

Answer (score 86):

You could do it this way:

```
res.status(400).json(json_response);
```

This will set the HTTP status code to 400, it works even in express 4.

Comment: `express deprecated res.json(status, obj): Use res.status(status).json(obj) instead`

So, `res.status(400).json(json_response)` would be accurate nowadays.

Comment: Yes, thanks... it is marked as deprecated, but still works :P  Your comment is valid, good point.

Comment: In favour of anwer - [`res.status(500).send({ error: "boo:(" });`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066976/432903)

Answer (score 47):

status of 200 will be the default when using `res.send`, `res.json`, etc.

You can set the status like `res.status(500).json({ error: 'something is wrong' });`

Often I'll do something like...

```
router.get('/something', function(req, res, next) {
  // Some stuff here
  if(err) {
    res.status(500);
    return next(err);
  }
  // More stuff here
});
```

Then have my error middleware send the response, and do anything else I need to do when there is an error.

Additionally: `res.sendStatus(status)` has been added as of version **4.9.0**
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus

Answer (score 29):

A list of [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

The good-practice regarding status response is to, predictably, send the proper HTTP status code depending on the error (4xx for client errors, 5xx for server errors), regarding the actual JSON response there's no "bible" but a good idea could be to send (again) the status and data as 2 different properties of the root object in a successful response (this way you are giving the client the chance to capture the status from the HTTP headers *and* the payload itself) and a 3rd property explaining the error in a human-understandable way in the case of an error.

[Stripe's](https://stripe.com/docs) API behaves similarly in the real world.

i.e.

**OK**

```
200, {status: 200, data: [...]}
```

**Error**

```
400, {status: 400, data: null, message: "You must send foo and bar to baz..."}
```

Answer (score 14):

I am using this in my Express.js application:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Welcome to the project-name api'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8):

**The standard way to get full HttpResponse that includes following properties**

1. body //contains your data
2. headers
3. ok
4. status
5. statusText
6. type
7. url

On **backend**, do this

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
    // res object have its own statusMessage property so utilize this
    res.statusText = 'You have signed-up succesfully'
    return res.status(200).send('You are doing a great job')
})
```

On **Frontend** e.g. in `Angular`, just do:

```
let url = `http://example.com/signup`
this.http.post(url, { profile: data }, {
    observe: 'response' // remember to add this, you'll get pure HttpResponse
}).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: I'm getting an error Cannot assign to `statusText` because it is a read-only property.

Answer (score 4):

```
res.status(500).jsonp(dataRes);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
  var data = {foo: "bar"};
  res.json(JSON.stringify(data));
}
catch (e) {
  res.status(500).json(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way of sending an error response would be `return res.status(400).send({ message: 'An error has occurred' })`.

Then, in your frontend you can catch it using something like this:

```
        url: your_url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('success', res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            err.response && err.response.data && this.setState({ apiResponse: err.response.data })
        })
```

Just logging `err` won't work, as your sent message object resides in `err.response.data`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
            return res.status(201).json({
                statusCode: req.statusCode,
                method: req.method,
                message: 'Question has been added'
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

### FOR IIS

If you are using *iisnode* to run nodejs through IIS, keep in mind that IIS by default replaces any error message you send.

This means that if you send `res.status(401).json({message: "Incorrect authorization token"})` You would get back `You do not have permission to view this directory or page`.

This behavior can be turned off by using adding the following code to your web.config file under `<system.webServer>` ([source](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/295#issuecomment-318446597)):

`<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />`

Answer (score 1):

`res.sendStatus(status)` has been added as of version 4.9.0

you can use one of these `res.sendStatus()` || `res.status()` methods

below is difference in between `res.sendStatus()` || `res.status()`

```
res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
res.sendStatus(403) // equivalent to res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
res.sendStatus(404) // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found')
res.sendStatus(500) // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
```

I hope someone finds this helpful
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone mentioned the fact that the order of method calls on `res` object is important.
I'm new to `nodejs` and didn't realize at first that res.json() does more than just setting the body of the response. It actually tries to infer the response status as well. So, if done like so:

```
res.json({"message": "Bad parameters"})
res.status(400)
```

The second line would be of no use, because based on the correctly built json `express/nodejs` will already infer the success status(`200`).

Comment: I think the main takeaway here is not order, but that NodeJS does infer status if not explicitly set.