# Express JS redirect to form with invalid email

Tags: node.js, forms, reactjs, express

I am new to nodeJS and I have been trying to create a registration form with validation.

The validation part is complete with sql query statements, but I am having trouble redirecting from my server side back to registration form with a message info such as 'Email address already exists'.

How do I process this on the client 'register.js' ?

**register.js**

```
      <form id='register-form' method="POST"  action="http://localhost:3306/register">
```

**server.js**

```
app.post('/register', (req,res) => {  
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;

let sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='" + email + "'";

db.query(sql,(err,result) => {
if (err) throw err;

if (result.length > 0) {
  console.log("user already exists");
  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/#/Register');
} else {
  insertUser(email,password);
  res.send(email + " has been added to database");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mutliple queries...

- I am not sure if your register.html file is within any folder(say, public) that is publicly accessed by using express static middleware. If yes, I hope you are setting the static middleware

**app.use(express.static('public'));**

- Do you want to send a response as Bad Request if email id is already present in DB?, then please try below 
  **if(!result.length)**

  **res.status(400).json('Email Id Already exists');**

OR

**res.status(400).send(400, {error:'Email Id Already exists'});**

- You need a body-parser to parse the URL encoded notation..sample code which worked for me:

  ```
  let express=require('express');
  let app = express();
  let server = require('http').createServer(app);

  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

  app.use(express.static('public'));


  app.post('/register', parseUrlencoded, (req,res) => {
      var email = req.body.email;
      var password = req.body.password;
        if (!email) {
          res.writeHead(404,
               {Location: 'http://localhost:3306/register.html'}
           );
          res.end();
         }
         else{
            res.status(200).json('email is not empty');
          }
  });
  server.listen(3306, ()=> console.log('app started'));
  ```

Some examples: [Proper way to set response status and JSON content in a REST API made with nodejs and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066785/proper-way-to-set-response-status-and-json-content-in-a-rest-api-made-with-nodej)

[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: yup, so 1 query checks if the email exists or not in the db and the other query insertUser(email,password) is for the SQL statement 'INSERT ....' 
I basically want to redirect back to my register form with a message displaying 'Email already exists' like in any generic form registration. My register form is not in a pubilic folder, rather I created a route for it using react routers