# NodeJs express error middleware parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to write a middleware to handle errors. But I cannot figure out how to send the correct format to my frontend. Below I am going to list all of my attempts in hopes of helping you help me.

### Attempt 1

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    const formatted = err;
    res.send(formatted)
});
```

result in postman

> { "code": 422 }

### Attempt 2

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    const formatted = `${err}`;
    res.send(formatted)
});
```

result (postman)

> Error: Request returned error code: 422 and body: {"status":422,"title":"The display name: build_id has already been used on this product.","type":"https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes","errors":{"display_name":"The display name: build_id has already been used on this product."}}

*That is the data i want but i need it in json*

### Question Why is there more data revealed after string interpolation? How can i format it to json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to set response status and JSON content in a REST API made with nodejs and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066785/proper-way-to-set-response-status-and-json-content-in-a-rest-api-made-with-nodej)

Comment: i looked at all these answers. I need something else.

Comment: The error your `console.log()` is not JSON it is a text.

I think your error is related to **bigcommerce** as it returned in the message

Comment: why is it text? I know the API res (when i try in postman) returns json... turns it to text somewhere

Comment: `Error: Request returned error code: 422 and body: {"status":422,"title":"The display name: build_id has already been used on this product.","type":"https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api#api-status-codes","errors":{"display_name":"The display name: build_id has already been used on this product."}}` <-- This is actually a text/string. I don't know why !! On my understanding this is related to any of your external library which is causing it. I would suggest you to focus on the problem you are getting in `console` which is `The display name: build_id has already been used on this product.`

Comment: ... and Then focus on the middleware issue. The response `{ "code": 422 }` is all we have. Problem is not in the middleware.

Comment: i dont want to fix the error. I want to send the error to my frontend

Comment: I have edited my answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for `res.json(err)` if I had to guess?

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

EDIT: Full example:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err) res.json(err)
});
```

Comment: That gives me json but not the full message... see `attempt 5` (just added)

Comment: You're still doing it wrong. I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: That is not retuning the full message. `>{"code": 422 }`... Look at the difference between attempt one and two. That is the problem i need to figure out

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            error: `${err}` // <-- edited
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you look at attempt 1 there is only `{ "code": 422 }` until attempt 2 where i did string interpolation. That is the same problem im having when i tried this. Only the code returns but not the message.

Comment: @Omar can you explain it a bit more about the context like what request you are sending etc, this will help us find the problem.

Comment: Did you tried sending the request via other platform or any browser??